# TeamBuild, Code Coverage & testrun config files

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have team build script for CI and nightly builds, both of which runs unit tests with code coverage.  I have specified the testrun config file and this include paths for the assemblies to instrument.

My problem is, the paths for the assemblies is absolute, eg:

```
<CodeCoverageItem 
binaryFile="C:\build\Product\PROJECT\Integration\Binaries\Debug\BlahBlah.Cache.dll"
pdbFile="C:\build\Product\PROJECT\Integration\Binaries\Debug\BlahBlah.Cache.pdb" 
instrumentInPlace="true" />
```

I would rather these used relative paths or I could specify $(OutDir) in there.

Has anyone solved this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use relative paths - paths that are relative to the *LocalTestRun.testrunconfig* file (which is typically stored in the same folder as the solution file).